# React jsonschema access formData

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, jsonschema

I am a complete beginner at react so a lot of simple syntax is confusing to me. I have a [jsonschema](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) form that renders perfectly fine in my create-react-app, but I don't understand how to get the data from the form when I submit it.

This is my App component (it renders I swear).

```
class App extends Component {
  App(){

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <div className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
          </div>
          <p className="App-intro">
            To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "json">
        <Form schema={schema}
          onChange={log("changed")}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          onError={log("errors")} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }  
}
```

The following is in the non JSX portion of my code.

```
const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    summary: {type: "string"},
    location: {type: "string"},
    description: {type: "string"},
    sendNotifications: {type: "boolean", default: false},
    ...and so forth...
}

const onSubmit = ({formData}) => console.log("yay I'm valid!");
```

If I leave it as it is, when I hit submit nothing happens. If I add () braces to the onSubmit call in the render method, it yields the error "cannot read property formData of undefined". I know virtually nothing about props, or how props are supposed to be defined. I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: is your component a `class` component? can you post the entire code of the component?

Comment: Yes this is my app component. Thank you for your response! I have updated the post.

Comment: add `this` to the function reference `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}`. there are other things that looks wrong in your code though, for example your constructor shouldnt be with the same name of your component. it should be `constructor(props){super(props)}`

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still verryy new to react so I have yet to write proper react code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `class` component you need to reference the handlers with the `this` key word `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}`.
As a side note you should change the way your constructor written.
See a working example of your code:

```js
const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

 schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    summary: {type: "string"},
    location: {type: "string"},
    description: {type: "string"},
    sendNotifications: {type: "boolean", default: false},
  }
}

onSubmit = ({formData}) => console.log("yay I'm valid!");

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <div className="App-header">
            <img src="" className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class = "json">
        <Form schema={this.schema}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit} 
        />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }  
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-jsonschema-form/dist/react-jsonschema-form.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!